# How to manage podfile.lock if team members use different versions of Cocoapods?

Tags: git, cocoapods

We're using Cocapods in our project and some teammates installed it directly from the AppCode so now they are using the last RC version while the other part of the team on stable 0.35.0.

Is it ok to keep things like this or should we use the same version of Cocoapods?

The only problem that we have now is the different Cocoapods version in podfile.lock after git pull. We can live with that but is it good practice to use Cocoapods in that way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I used to stick with the exactly the same CocoaPods version, everybody else within the team uses. Each update should be introduced as a separate Pull Request.

Additionally to what **@Keith Smiley** said, keeping the version same, would reduce the "noise" in CocoaPods's configuration files for your dependancies upon each `pod install` and `pod update` runs. Especially, when a repo does **not** ignore *Pods* directory.

[Check out my notes](https://github.com/evgeniyd/Xcode-CocoaPods-Notes), about CocoaPods `Podfile.lock` and maintaining the same version the project is being set up with.

Comment: It looks that your Notes link is broken.

Comment: Hey @RicardoMontesinos. Indeed. I made the Github repo private, and it's been a while since I updated the notes the last time.Right now, many teams use Gemfile and Bundler to keep the local environment the same across all the team members when it comes to CocoaPods version.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would all be using the same, and newest version of CocoaPods. It's always possible that new versions of CocoaPods introduce or remove features that makes using multiple different versions inconvenient. The worst case scenario is that a newer version of CocoaPods makes breaking changes and using the two different versions becomes impossible. Unless you notice something like that it shouldn't be a problem. In the meantime I would ignore the version number change  in your `Podfile.lock` each time a different team member runs `pod install`.